# Molarity exercises

Tags: stoichiometry, concentration

Can anyone direct me to a good book with lots of molarity exercises, i really want to practice this and would like to find as many types of exercises involving molarity. I of course did google this and there are some, but usually they are three or four exercises per resource.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This type of question might not cut it on Chemistry.SE because it is primarily opinion based, and as you mentioned can be answered by a google search.

Comment: It's also essentially a service recommendation. However, I have a better [Google search for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=solution+stoichiometry+practice+problems+with+answers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a). The first site have 16 problems, the second 4, the third has 25, the four 24, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can try rc mukherjee,an indian author for preliminary level.and schaum publishers for higher level.